# My question is about creating a trigger after insert?

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I need to create a trigger after insert.But the ex i have seen do not work.Can anyone help me with a ex of a similar trigger.
Thank a lot!!

an example it is :

`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  TRG_ACCT_IDW

    AFTER INSERT
ON ACNTGROUPS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :NEW.TYPE = '1' then INSERT INTO IDWORKS_HC
(ACCOUNT,IDW_CATEGORYNO,GRTYPE)
VALUES
(:NEW.ACCOUNT,:NEW.GROUP_,:NEW.TYPE); END IF; END;`

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Comment: Well then apparently you do not have a table named `TICKET_NOTIFICE_T` or `TICKET_NOTIFICE`

Comment: Do you want to have an insert into TICKET_NOTIFICE for each row that is inserted into TICKET, or just one row, if you've added multiple rows into TICKET in one go?

Comment: NO THE BOTH TABLE EXIST,  and i have already add the dates the first table has to the second, but now i need the triger that after new rows insert do what i have explain

Comment: @Boneist i need for those column i have show up. i get each new row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger should look something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ticket_notifice_t
  AFTER INSERT ON ticket
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO ticket_notifice
    (id,
     useridrichiedente,
     stato,
     nosologico)
  VALUES
    (:new.id,
     :new.useridrichiedente,
     :new.stato,
     :new.nosologico);
END ticket_notifice_t;
/
```

Note the presence of the `FOR EACH ROW` and the colon (:) before each reference to the `new` record.

In addition, this assumes that the schema you are creating the trigger on has privileges on the ticket and ticket_notifice tables and can create triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Most time ORA-00942 "table or view does not exist" is a problem in privilegues.

Try to grant rights to public:

```
GRANT ALL ON TICKET_NOTIFICE TO PUBLIC
```

If this works you know you messed up your configuration.

Check which user needs which rights. In you case the executing uesr needs `insert` on `TICKET_NOTIFICE`, i think.

Comment: `GRANT ALL ... TO PUBLIC` is maybe not the smartest solution in terms of security.

Comment: Sure. But the fastest to check if this is a problem. In addition it works if xxxxxx doesn't know which user he's using.

Comment: @xxxxxxxxxxx what do you mean by "after update". Do you mean that you want the trigger to fire only after an update? Or after an insert and an update? if so, you should look at the second row in my answer and amend it accordingly. If you need to check for whether you're doing an insert or update in your trigger body (e.g. because you need to do something different), you can use `if inserting then ... end if;` or `if updating then ... end if;`

Comment: yeah but update is singel row  and when excetute i have an error with primary key violent

Comment: This is the triger create or replace TRIGGER ticket_notifice_t
  AFTER UPDATE OF  stato ON tickets
  FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
  
BEGIN
 UPDATE ticket_notifice
   SET id=:new.id,
     useridrichiedente=:new.useridrichiedente,
     stato= :new.stato,
     nosologico= :new.nosologico,
     OPERAZIONE=:new.OPERAZIONE
  WHERE :NEW.STATO='1'
END ticket_notifice_t;

Comment: This sounds like it should be a new question. Please create a new question with a test case that produces the error (e.g. create table statement (including the primary key constraints, etc), create trigger statement, insert statements to populate your table, plus the update statement that causes you the error.